# Python: Dividing a string into substrings

Tags: python

I have a bunch of mathematical expressions stored as strings. Here's a short one:

```
stringy = "((2+2)-(3+5)-6)"
```

I want to break this string up into a list that contains ONLY the information in each "sub-parenthetical phrase" (I'm sure there's a better way to phrase that.) So my yield would be:

```
['2+2','3+5']
```

I have a couple of ideas about how to do this, but I keep running into a "okay, now what" issue.

For example:

```
for x in stringy:
    substring = stringy[stringy.find('('+1 : stringy.find(')')+1]
    stringlist.append(substring)
```

Works just peachy to return 2+2, but that's about as far as it goes, and I am completely blanking on how to move through the remainder...

Comment: Write an actual parser. (Using [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) or [Parsley](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Parsley) or [ANTLR](http://www.antlr3.org/) or whatever.)

Comment: But this problem is solvable in O(n) since it's reduceable to the wordproblem of regular grammars while a parser needs at least O(n^3) since it needs contextfree grammars. And a parser is way more code to write - but cleaner for sure...

Comment: What do you want to do for, say, `((2*(2+2))-(3+5)-6)`? Should you get `2*(2+2)`, `2+2`, both, or neither?

Comment: @RouvenB. Huh? Algorithms for parsing a subset of CFGs good enough for most "programming-ish" languages (like expressions) all have O(n) complexity. (At least LL, LALR, and packrat parsing do, according to wiki, for LL it's actually very obvious why that's the case. The first two also have memory complexity that's constant or a factor of the resulting parse tree depth.) You only need more than linear time if you need to work with ambiguous grammars.

Comment: True story. My fault...

Comment: @abarnert- thank you, that point is extremely helpful because it makes me realize that doing what I had intended to do with this is actually NOT going to be useful for me! I'll have to find another way to handle the incoming data.

Answer (score 2):

One way using regex:

```
import re
stringy = "((2+2)-(3+5)-6)"
for exp in re.findall("\(([\s\d+*/-]+)\)", stringy):
    print exp
```

**Output**

```
2+2
3+5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions like the following:

```
import re

x = "((2+2)-(3+5)-6)"

re.findall(r"(?<=\()[0-9+/*-]+(?=\))", x)
```

Result:

```
['2+2', '3+5']
```